# How to check the file type in a script

Tags: shell-script, files, file-command

I want to do a loop for all the images in a directory. The images doesn't have extension so I have to read the first bytes of the image to know its type. The loop should end up being something like.

```
for file in *
do
    if [ file --mime-type -b ]
    then
        ***
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `case` statement and *command substitution* :

```
for file in *; do
    case $(file --mime-type -b "$file") in
        image/*g)        ... ;;
        text/plain)      ... ;;
        application/xml) ... ;;
        application/zip) ... ;;
        *)               ... ;;
    esac
done
```

Check :
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case

#### EDIT

if you insist to don't use `case` but an `if` statement using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
if [[ $(file --mime-type -b "$file") == image/*g ]]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

Comment: How would it be with the if statement? `if (($(file --mime-type -b file) == "image/*g"))`

Comment: POST edited accordingly